# how to increase sprite speed?

Tags: android, game-physics

I am working on an android game. I have set the FPS to 30. It is going fine. There are "speed up" objects on the road. When a sprite encounters one, it will increase sprite speed.

I have increased the FPS, but is has no effect. I need to show a particular sprite animation first not all.

```
public void run()
{
    while(running)
    {
        Canvas canvas=null;
        try
        {
            canvas=view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (view.getHolder())
            {
                beginTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                view.update();

                view.onDraw(canvas);
                timediff=System.currentTimeMillis()-beginTime;
                sleepTime=(int) (FRAME_PERIOD-timediff);

                Log.i(TAG, "sleepTime"+sleepTime);
                if(sleepTime>0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Thread sleep"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, ""+e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if(canvas!=null)
            {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What? (need to type more to be able to comment)

Comment: You have code, right? Maybe you should share that.

Comment: Tough to say without code. First I would verify that when the sprite encounters a "speed up" object, that an event is being generated and then the event handler is called. Also, I don't know that increased FPS is the answer. Instead maybe increase the rate that the sprite is traveling. For example if it is traveling at 10m/sec, then increase it to 20m/sec.

Comment: sprite is not traveling, only road is moving , sprite is fixed a position.I just animate sprite.But when it becomes fast,road is moving fast but animation is not. I want to animate it fast.

Comment: @AndrewArnold I have post my code here